# How to add a context menu(show on right-clilck) to the chrome dev tools Elements page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, browser-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and I would like to add a new option to be displayed on right click of the "search" bar within the developer tools elements tab.

Something like this:

[image]

I was able to add the context menu on the current active page like this:

[image]

But it does not apply to the dev tools window.

Comment: There's no such API.